# Testing if Boost library was compiled correctly

Tags: software-installation, boost

Does the Boost library have a test suite that tells if the Boost library installation is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Unit Test
at boost source's directory

`pushd tools/build/test; python test_all.py; popd`

Regression Test

pushd status; b2 --toolset=intel; popd

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/boost.html